# Python - Using two interdependent classes and a for loop

Tags: python, loops, class

My question is basically the following: I have two classes:

- Class 1 that does something in a loop (web scraping)
- Class 2 that has different functions to automize things someone has to do in this loop and similar loops in the future.

The idea is to abstract Class 1 as much as possible.

Example: Class 2 has a function that "pauses like a human" after certain iterations

(excerpt)

```
    def pause_like_human(self):
    ''' Pausing long every x-th iteration or else short '''
    # every 20th iteration - wait for 5-10 minutes before continuing
    if self.index_no % self.index_counter == 0:
        timestamp = time.localtime()
        return print("Let's wait " + str(self.waiting_time_long) + " seconds! The time is: "\
              + str(timestamp.tm_hour) + ":" + str(timestamp.tm_min) + ":"\
                  + str(timestamp.tm_sec)), time.sleep(self.waiting_time_long)
    else:
        return print("Let's continue! ... after " + str(self.waiting_time_short) + " seconds..."), time.sleep(self.waiting_time_short)
```

Now my problem is that I would need to import "index_no" from the loop I am using in class 2... over and over again.

(index_no is in this loop:)

```
        for index_no, city in enumerate(self.df['column'][len(self.dic)-1:], start = len(self.dic)-1):
```

To me it sounds like this would be very inefficient - does someone have a better idea?

Comment: `return print(...)` makes no sense since `print` always returns `None`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if its not the 20th iteration it prints out "Let's continue[...]"

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear. My comment didn't address the problem you described (since I doubt that I understood what you want). I just wanted to explain that `return print(...)` is not useful.

Comment: No worries. But I am curious why it is not useful... When I execute the other loop and want to basically see the progress / what is happening - aren't I am happy about the print statement showing what is happening?

Comment: For that use case `print` is OK. But you don't need the `return`. If you use `return` it looks like you want to give back something useful from the function, but in this case it's just the return value of `print` and that is always `None`, so checking the return value makes no sense anyway. BTW, a function without a `return` statement alredy returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer for me specifically seems to be that I simply abstract the code even more. This will turn my "complicated" loop into a very easy loop and my two classes into one class.
Class 1 turns to a longer list with links, but actually well prepared.
Class 2 turns into a more generalised class with most of the functionality of the former class 1 inherited already.

I wouldnt mind leaving this post open if someone comes up with a general help or hints...